# SQL Script Errors in phpMyAdamin - Foreign Key Restraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, xampp

I am creating a SQL script and importing it into phpMyAdmin. Here is the code:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Carpool;
CREATE DATABASE Carpool;
USE Carpool;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    username    varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    firstname   varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    lastname    varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    age         int(10)         NOT NULL,
    email       varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    gender      varchar(1)      NOT NULL,
    passhash    varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(username)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
    car_id      int(50)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cartype     varchar(50),
    neatness    varchar(50),
    color       varchar(50),
    seats       int(50),
PRIMARY KEY(car_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS startinglocation (
    startinglocation_id int(100)        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address             varchar(200)    NOT NULL,
    zipcode             varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    city                varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    state               varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    longitude           float(10)       NOT NULL,
    latitude            float(10)       NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(startinglocation_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS endinglocation (
    endinglocation_id   int(100)        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    address             varchar(200)    NOT NULL,
    zipcode             varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    city                varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    state               varchar(50)     NOT NULL,
    longitude           float(10)       NOT NULL,
    latitude            float(10)       NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(endinglocation_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carpool (

    car_id              int(50),
    carpool_id          int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    datetime            varchar(50),
    duration            varchar(50),
    numberofpassengers  int(10),
    startingtime        varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    endingtime          varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    recurrencelevel     int(10),
    startinglocation_id int(100),
    endinglocation_id   int(100),
PRIMARY KEY(carpool_id),
FOREIGN KEY(car_id)
    REFERENCES cars(car_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(startinglocation_id)
    REFERENCES startinglocation(startinglocation_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(endinglocation_id)
    REFERENCES endinglocation(endinglocation_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS driver (
    username    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    carpool_id  int(50)     NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (username)
    REFERENCES users(username)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (carpool_id)
    REFERENCES carpool(carpool_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passenger (
    username        varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    carpool_id      int(50)     NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (username)
    REFERENCES users(username)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (carpool_id)
    REFERENCES carpool(carpool_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
    
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON *
TO mgs_user
IDENTIFIED BY 'Password1';
```

And I am receiving this as the error report:

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS carpool (

    car_id              int(50),
    carpool_id          int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    datetime            varchar(50),
    duration            varchar(50),
    numberofpassengers  int(10),
    startingtime        varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    endingtime          varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    recurrencelevel     int(10),
    startinglocation_id int(100),
    endinglocation_id   int(100),
PRIMARY KEY(carpool_id),
FOREIGN KEY(car_id)
    REFERENCES cars(car_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(startinglocation_id)
    REFERENCES startinglocation(startinglocation_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(endinglocation_id)
    REFERENCES endinglocation(endinglocation_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1005 - Can't create table `carpool`.`driver` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

I feel like I referenced the tables correctly for the foreign keys, but have been unsuccessful with minor changes I have tried.

Comment: You can not reference a table which is not defined yet. So change the order of table creation.

Comment: I edited the code above to show that is a method I have tried. I made sure all the foreign keys are after the table that is being referenced has been created. It is producing the same error.

Comment: driver.username and users.username are not of the same type (length). Why don't you use an auto_incrementing user_id?

Comment: And `ON DELETE SET NULL` is not going to work on a `NOT NULL` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `carpool` table is referencing the `startinglocation` and `endinglocation` tables, so it needs to be created after them.

Simply change the creation order, doing `startinglocation` and `endinglocation` tables at the beginning of your script, and it should work.

@Paul Spiegel gave you the answer to the second part of your question: `driver` and `passenger` tables are referencing `users.username` with a different type.

Comment: I edited the code above to show that is a method I have tried. I made sure all the foreign keys are after the table that is being referenced has been created. It is producing the same error.

Comment: Got it. @Paul Spiegel, created auto_incrementing user_id and changed type to int of same length. Removed ON DELETE SET NULL for NOT NULL columns. Verified correct order of tables per Anthony Drogon. Thanks for the help.